Encrypting and Decrypting Using A256GCM Algorithm
When I attempted to encrypt a JWT using the A256GCM algorithm, I received this exception. I am using version 6.35.0 of the Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens library.
string token = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Audience = "api1",
    Issuer = "https://test.com",
    Claims = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "sub", "811e790749a24d8a8f766e1a44dca28a" } },
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256),
    EncryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(publicEncryptionKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaOAEP, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256Gcm) // Line that causes the exception below.
});

This is the exception thrown:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenEncryptionFailedException: 'IDX10617: Encryption failed. Keywrap is only supported for: 'A128CBC-HS256', 'A192CBC-HS384' and 'A256CBC-HS512'. The content encryption specified is: 'A256GCM'.'

I have a few questions:

Does this mean that if I try to decrypt a JWE that was encrypted
using this algorithm, it will fail as well?
Are there alternatives
that I can use to be able to use A256GCM in .NET 6.0?


Have you tried on the latest build?

According to this post, sec. Creating JWE tokens in .NET, A256GCM is not supported as encryption algorithm. On .NET 8 and with Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 7.5.2 I get the same error message as you. Regarding question 1: Most likely because A256GCM is not supported. Regarding question 2: Use a JOSE library that supports A256GCM, e.g. jose-jwt.

Topaco, is it possible to use the jose-jwt library to create a SecurityKey object that can decrypt an A256GCM-encrypted JWE?

It's not clear to me why using jose-jwt should require the SecurityKey class (or a derivation of it, since SecurityKey is abstract) at all. If you intend to extend the functionality of Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens with jose-jwt: This is rather unlikely to work, as these are different libraries. jose-jwt is a standalone library with its own classes, you will find many examples in the documentation, e.g. for JWE.

I understand, but in ASP.NET Core, you validate JWTs and JWEs using the Services.AddAuthentication() method. jose-jwt decrypts the JWE on its own, and so I couldn't use Services.AddAuthentication() with it. I don't want a client application to decrypt this JWE and send the plainText (which is the JWT) since it will expose the data of said JWT which defeats the purpose of having a JWE in the first place.

You should explain such constraints from the beginning in the question, but you are only asking about encryption/decryption with A256GCM. Apart from pointing out that the jose-jwt documentation contains a section on ASP.NET Core MVC JWT Authentication (which you've probably already seen and which in I don't know if it's relevant to you in any way), I'm afraid I can't help you further.

I was able to make it work; thank you for guiding me to use the jose-jwt library. Can you create an answer so that I can mark it as such?
